# Putting multiple labels in a second form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

Hi good day guys i would just like to ask if this is a good code for putting multiple labels in a second form with the text from the first form using one button? Thanks in advance and happy coding to all.

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

Dim lbl As Label = New Label     'Create your Label
    'change the location..    
    lbl.Location = New Point(50, 50) 'Set Label Location
    lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text         'Set Label Text
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black       'Set Label ForeColor
    frm2.Controls.Add(lbl)           'Add Label to it

    Return

    'change the location..    
    lbl.Location = New Point(10, 20) 'Set Label Location
    lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text         'Set Label Text
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black       'Set Label ForeColor
    frm2.Controls.Add(lbl)           'Add Label to it

    Return

End Sub
```

it only shows the first label but it does not show the next labels that I will input...

form2 codes

```
Public Class Form2
Public lbl As New Label
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)

End Sub
```

End Class

Problem solved..Many thanks to Sir Plutonix and Steve for their help I really appreciate it :) I accepted the suggestion of Plutonix to use multiple textboxes rather than one textbox and I used the sample code of Steve in starting my project.. Many thanks again :)

Comment: Perhaps if you remove the return before the creation of the second label :-)

Comment: @Steve Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form2'.

Comment: remove the return AND add `lbl = New Label` but it will have the same text

Comment: @Plutonix sir its still the same after i remove those.

Comment: Did you mean `frm2`? There is no object named Form2. But are you sure that this is all the code in this procedure? Where do you get that frm2 variable?

Comment: @Steve sir I have a form 2 wait i will post the codes also.. thanks! :)

Comment: @Steve I posted the codes of my form2 already sir :) thanks again

Comment: is Form2/frm2 showing when this code runs?

Comment: @Plutonix yes and with the first label and the supposed text that I want is working fine but after the second input it produces and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a global class level variable that keeps a reference to your Form2, then when you click the button and the global class level variable is nothing (first time creation) you create the Form2 instance, add the labels and most important add an event handler that will be called when the frm2 instance will be closed. Then show the form and bring it to the forefront.
If your user reclicks on the button, a new form will not be created (frm2 is not nothing at this point), instead, if your user closes the frm2 the event handler will be called and you reset the internal class level variable to nothing. Now if you user clicks again on the button the frm2 will be recreated

```
Private frm2 As Form2

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    if frm2 Is Nothing then
       frm2 = new Form2
       AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Me.Form2HasBeenClosed

       Dim lbl As Label = New Label     
       lbl.Location = New Point(50, 50) 
       lbl.Text = "FirstLabelText"
       lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black     

       frm2.Controls.Add(lbl)          

       Dim lbl2 = New Label
       lbl2.Location = New Point(10, 20) 
       lbl2.Text = "TextForSecondLabel"
       lbl2.ForeColor = Color.Black      
       frm2.Controls.Add(lbl2)         
   End if

   frm2.Show()
   frm2.BringToFront
End Sub  

Sub Form2HasBeenClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
   frm2 = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    if frm2 IsNot Nothing Then
        frm2.Show(Me)            'Show Second Form  
    End If      
End Sub
```

Comment: yes sir this is a good code but I have the textbox in form1 that will make the text show on a label on form2 :)

Comment: No sir I mean when I change it to textbox1.text it will just show the first label that I created and it will overwrite the second one. thanks :)

Comment: If you assign the same textbox.text to two different labels (note that I have created a new label with a different name, I have not reused the same label)

Comment: yes sir thats the problem here I need to put the text on the same textbox which gives me the dilemma.. thanks :)

Comment: are you trying to enter text into a TB, click to make Label1; then enter new text and click to make Label2?

Comment: @Plutonix, too late here, it is time to go to bed, I leave the solution to you, bye

Comment: much easier to add another TextBox for the 2nd label, or make a label factory.  the problem is that you need more than just different text: the location must change and form1(?) doesnt have that capability

Comment: @Plutonix any possible solutions to my problem with making too many textbox because I just need one textbox. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Private LabelCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button3_Click(yada yada yada

' I think this is actually fixing a nonexistant problem
' stemming from misunderstanding the issue
if frm2 Is Nothing then
   frm2 = new Form2
   AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Me.Form2HasBeenClosed

   Dim lbl As Label = New Label 
   lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text
   lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black 

   Select Case LabelCount
       Case 0
          lbl.Location = New Point(50, 50) 
       Case 1
          lbl.Location = New Point(10, 20) 

       Case Else
          ' not specified
          Exit Sub
   End Select
   LabelCount +=1                  ' dont forget this
   frm2.Controls.Add(lbl)

End if

 frm2.Show()
 frm2.BringToFront
 End Sub
```

Comment: it does not fix the problem it still the same it overwrites the previous label that I created. But i will just stick to your suggestion of making many textboxes on the first form in order to make  the problem not so complicated.. Many thanks man :)

Comment: there was an edit - see the 'LabelCount +=1` i forgot it at first

Comment: Yeah even i include labelcount +=1 it still acts the same i dont know why I just think that this problem is too complicated for a human being to solve right now I think only a superhuman can solve this that is why your suggestion a while ago really struck me in the head to make life easier just make multiple TB on the first form :p